# What is the point of the Application URL of Facebook Application registeration?

Tags: java, android, facebook, oauth

I am developing an Android application for which I would like to add Facebook functionality using Facebook's Android SDK. I have registered the application and acquired the ID and Secret, but what is the point of the URL? Am I supposed to install something on my website on that specific URL so that I Facebook can do the OAuth key exchange?

If so, then what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application URL is basically used for callback purposes, so that the `access_token` may be returned to the callback and your application handle the returned result.

Comment: You mean I don't really have to put anything in my website, or do I have to put a OAuth module or something? The documentation is really vague about this.

Comment: Facebook uses OAuth 2 API specification so you'll have to read the OAuth 2 specification to see if callback url is required.

Comment: Thank you, it isn't required. I can go along happily just with the application ID.